# Create new div arround anchor link when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I achieve this behaviors onclick with jquery :

**default state:**

```
<a href="something.html">Anchor</a>
```

**click state**

```
<div class="highlight">
<a href="something.html">Anchor</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fastest way to do this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).wrap($('<div/>', { 'class': 'highlight'}));
});
```

However, this is probably what you want, much simpler just use whatever CSS effect you want:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('highlight'});
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can use the jQuery "wrap" function:

```
$('#idOfAnchor').click(function(a) {
  $(a).wrap($('<div/>').addClass('highlight'));
});
```

That seems like kind-of a funny idea however. Why not just add the class directly to the `<a>` element itself?

Oh sorry - your question says "clicked" but the explanation says "hover". That's going to be a little trickier, because you're going to want to get rid of that extra div when you mouse out. Again, if this were my page, I just wouldn't do that at all. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

**edit again:** ok now it says "click" again :-)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout jQuery's [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.

```
$(this).wrap('<div class="highlight"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just style a:hover?

Something like this in CSS:

```
.highlight a {
    /* style */
}

.highlight a:hover {
    /* hover style */
}
```

Then change your HTML to:

```
<a href="something.html" class='highlight'>Anchor</a>
```