# Wrapping multiple images inside a <div> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I need to find all the images inside a `div`, and wrap a `div` around them. Here's the code I come up with, but that's not working! Why?

```js
jQuery(function() {
  my_selection = [];
  $('.post').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).find('img').length > 1) {
      my_selection.push(['.post:eq(' + i + ')']);
    }
  });
  $(my_selection.join(',')).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
$('.post img').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

`.post img` will get a collection of `IMG` tags within your .post container, and `wrapAll` applies the `DIV` around each of them.

The [manual page for the wrapAll function](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) actually has quite a close example to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say because I can't see your markup but something like:

```
$('.post img').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

this works!

```
$('.post').each(function(){
    var container = $(this);
    $('img', container).wrapAll('<div class="slideshow" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('.post img').each(function() {
      $(this).wrap($('<div/>', { 'class': 'wrapper'}));
    });
```

Here is a link to the similar question I asked :

[Create new div arround anchor link when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480716/create-new-div-arround-anchor-link-when-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function (){
   $(this).wrap('<div class="new" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a div around each img inside a .post:

```
$('.post img').wrap('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

Wrap a div around each post that has a img:

```
$('.post:has(img)').wrap('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

Move all divs that have an img inside a wrapper div:

```
$('<div class="wrapper" />').append($('.post:has(img)'));
```